# How can I call WordPress core functions in external scripts?

Tags: php

I'm trying to develop a code to call some Codex functions (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) the problem is simple, I don't find any doc where read about how to start.

I have a PHP file with this line for example:

```
<?php

 $website = "http://example.com";
 $userdata = array(
 'user_login'  =>  'login_name',
 'user_url'    =>  $website,
 'user_pass'   =>  NULL  // When creating an user, `user_pass` is expected.
);

 $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

 //On success
 if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
 echo "User created : ". $user_id;
 }

?>
```

Where I need to put this code to check if works?
Where I need to call it? 
Must I create a plugin? Can I call those functions from a script in a specific folder?

For example, the funcion wp_insert_user is in /wp-includes/user.php, can I call the function just including the script?

```
include('user.php')
```

Where are the rest of the functions?

Someone knows an specific manual with a simple doc? I'm getting crazy.

This is my first script for a CMS and I don't undertand how it works, but I dont find manuals or simple doc.

Comment: To clear up some confusion... the "Codex" is WordPress core documentation.  These functions are built-in to WP core and are already available.  Codex is not an add-on for WordPress.  I would recommend reviewing the documentation on plugin development and find a tutorial or two about writing a basic plugin.  This will give you a better understanding of how WP executes and the proper ways to expand the core functionality.   https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: I had tried to develop a plugin, the package was built here: http://wppb.me/. I can see my plugin listed in my admin panel. The problem is when I try to call some of the functions, Wordpress fail, it says that the function doesn't exist.

Comment: Context is everything here as WP core follows a very complex flow with each request.  Depending on where and where your code is executed, certain classes and globals of the WP environment may or may not be available.  Understanding where to hook or trigger your code is a difficult concept for those new to WP.   https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-action-hooks-and-filter-hooks-an-introduction-4163

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I get the solution.

To call functions from Wordpress from a custom script, you need to import wp-load:

```
require_once("/path/wp-load.php");
```

Thats all, I can work fine with those functions. I save my own script in the root of my PHP Wordpress and I didn't need a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

External files can easily access the wordpress functions. You just need to include the file `wp-load.php` in your external file.
The `wp-load.php` file is located in root of your wordpress installation.
Example: Suppose your file is `test.php` located at root directory of wordpress installation.

```
<?php
    require_once('wp-load.php');
    // Your custom code
?>
```

Source: [How to access WordPress functions in external file](https://webolute.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-access-wordpress-functions-in-external-file)